# (onChange) not working for Angular4 select in dropbox

Tags: javascript, angular

new to angular 4 and i'm building something.

I have a couple components, one of them has this as its html:

```
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid black;">
<br>
<div class="col s1"><h2 class="titleClass">Categories: </h2></div>
    <div *ngFor="let number of numbersList"> 
    <div class="input-field col s2" *ngIf="number < numberOfCategoriesShown">
        <select id={{number}} (onChange)="onChange()" >
            <option value={{allString}}></option>
            <option value={{type}} *ngFor="let type of categoryList[number]">{{type}}</option>
        </select>
        <label>Category {{number + 1}}</label>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

<button (click)="onChange()"></button>
```

I want a function to be called whenever I change a value in one of those select objects. The function is called onChange.

However, for whatever reason, it's not working. But the (click)="onChange()" at the bottom is. Also funnily enough, if I change the value of the comboBox then try clicking the button, then the button doesn't work either.

Could anyone help me please? I've decleared the onChange function inside the component's class.

Here is what my .ts file looks like:

```
  import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { VideoService } from '../../services/video.service';
import { Video } from '../../../assets/video';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filtering',
  templateUrl: './filtering.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filtering.component.css'],
  providers: [VideoService]
})
export class FilteringComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() 
  changeDetection;

  categoryList: Set<String>[] = new Array();
  numbersList: number[] = new Array();
  tagSet  = new Set<String>();
  allString = 'ALL';
  numberOfCategoriesShown = 10;
  selectedItem;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(changes)); 
  }

  constructor(private videoService: VideoService) { 

    for (let i = 0; i < this.videoService.getVideos().length; i++) {
      const categoryTypes = this.videoService.getVideos()[i].category.split('->');
      for (let j = 0; j < categoryTypes.length ; j++) {
        if (this.categoryList.length <= j) {
          this.categoryList.push(new Set());
          this.numbersList.push(this.categoryList.length - 1);
        }
        this.categoryList[j].add(categoryTypes[j]);
      }

      this.tagSet.add(this.videoService.getVideos()[i].tags);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onChange(newValue) {
    console.log('woop'); 
  }

}
```

Comment: I've tried that, still no luck.

Comment: Please provide a demo (plunker/stackblitz..) that showcases this issue :)

Comment: The problem lies somewhere else. I created a stackblitz demo from your code, and it works as expected, when you fix the binding to `(change)="onChange()"`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-s7sqfo

Answer (score 9):

There is no onChange, it is **`(change)`**

```
  <select id={{number}} (change)="onChange()" >
```

Proper way is to use **`ngModelChange`**

```
<select id={{number}}   [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onChange()" >
            <option value={{allString}}></option>
            <option value={{type}} *ngFor="let type of categoryList[number]">{{type}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: For whatever reason i've tried both those things and neither have worked for me. It's very frustrating.

Comment: can you post your categorList

Comment: Changing (onChange) to (change) and then (after that didn't work)

Comment: ngModelChange is unfortunately not working either. I am rather confused since that is what all the other sources on the internet are suggesting too.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(categoryList)); and post here

Comment: [{},{},{},{}]
Hmm, very confusing, the select boxes are being populated appropriately.

Comment: onChange for angular

Answer (score 2):

As @Sajeetharan correctly points, your use of `onChange` is incorrect.

If using the standard HTML controls, the event you want is `change`. But if you're using `Angular Material` (your own answer hints to that), you need to use `selectionChange` instead of `change`. Checkout the API [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, when I use the materialise css framework, (change) does not work, but if I do not use it, it does work.